# waf copy a file from source tree to the build tree

Tags: copy, waf, sequencing

I have the following snippet, to copy a file *as-is* to the build dir:

```
for m in std_mibs:
    print("Copying", m)
    bld(name       = 'cpstdmib',
        rule       = 'cp -f ${SRC} ${TGT}',
        #source     =  m + '.mib',
        source     =  bld.path.make_node(m + '.mib'), # <-- section 5.3.3 of the waf book
        target     =  bld.path.get_bld().make_node(m + '.mib')
        )
```

I see that this rule, though hit (from the print), the copy doesnt seem to be happening!
I also changed the source to use the `make_node` as shown, in an example in the section *5.3.3* of the waf book, still no luck! Am I missing something obvious here!?

Also, I have some rules after this, which rely on the copied files, and I tried adding
an intervening

```
bld.add_group()
```

I hope that the sequencing will work, if this copy succeeds

Answer (score 1):

If you run the rule once, it will not be run again until source is updated. This is true even if the target is deleted, for instance (which is probably how you were testing.)

If you want to recopy if the target is deleted, you will need `always=True`, or you'll need to check for existence and set `target.sig = None`.

Comment: I'm still investigating this, clearly this is not a full or complete solution. See also the bottom part of https://download.samba.org/pub/unpacked/waf/docs/book/nodes.txt, which is also incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives:

- `features="subst"` with `is_copy=True`:

  ```
   bld(features='subst', source='wscript', target='wscript', is_copy=True)
  ```
- `waflib.extras.buildcopy` like this:

  ```
  from waflib.extras import buildcopy
  #...
  def build(bld):
      bld(features='buildcopy',buildcopy_source=['file'])
  ```

`cp` is not platform independent.

A `task_gen` object is created, which later will become a `Task`, that will be executed before `process_sources`. Don't expect an immediate effect.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `buildcopy` module isn't distributed with waf anymore so you have to copy the `buildcopy.py` file into your project. Then just import using `import buildcopy`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into your `out` dir, there will be `out/${TGT}` (not exactly, but `${TGT}` path relative to your `top` directory)

---

This is totally to be expected behaviour, since you do not want to modify your source tree when building.